# Image preprocessing as a Keras lambda layer vs preprocessing on its own

Tags: python, keras, resnet

I'm trying to apply preprocessing imported from a resnet50 module in Keras before propagating the images through the network. Since I got errors when trying to apply it in the generator object, I added it to the network as a lambda layer.

But since the model was worse than one that I trained previously when I was applying preprocessing on each image separately, I compared the results of both approaches and they seem very different, although I can't see what's different about the applied operations.

```
import keras
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(preprocess_input, name='preprocessing', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))

file = '/path/to/an/image.jpeg'
x = np.array(image.img_to_array(image.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))))

preprocessed_x = preprocess_input(x)
predicted_x = model.predict(x.reshape(1,224,224,3)).reshape(224,224,3)
```

Results (left: preprocessing function used directly; right: preprocessing as a lambda layer.

### [image: Using the preprocessing function directly] [image: Using preprocessing function in a model as a lambda function]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be a bug in keras code, but I found that `preprocess_input(x)` is modifying `x` in place.

See:

```
x = np.array(image.img_to_array(image.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))))
print("x before preprocess - max: " + str(x.max()) + " / min: " + str(x.min()))
preprocessed_x = preprocess_input(x)
print("x after preprocess - max: " + str(x.max()) + " / min: " + str(x.min()))
```

Results:

```
x before preprocess - max: 255.0 / min: 0.0
x after preprocess - max: 151.061 / min: -123.68
```

I'd certainly not expect this behavior at first, but thinking twice, it spares memory (which is valuable when neural networking...).

If you run your test with the model version before the numpy version, the problem will not happen (because the model, working in tensors, won't modify x in place).

## Preprocess within or outside the model?

I'd say it's better to preprocess images outside the model, in the generator.
This way you get a faster execution when training and predicting.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. That means I again have no idea why the features extracted using both of these techniques turn out to have different values.

Comment: In one case, you're passing the original image for the model to process. In the other case, you're passing a processed image and the model processes it again.

Comment: I am not doing the preprocessing part when I'm extracting the features using a Lambda layer before the CNN.

And I can't provide the preprocess_input function to the generator because there's a bug producing this error: '‘JpegImageFile’ object is not subscriptable'. Some people suggest downgrading keras but I don't find that to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.... did you post any question about the error in the generator?

Comment: No, because I was using the lambda layer as a workaround. Sorry, I was referring to this thread: http://forums.fast.ai/t/keras-lesson1-jpegimagefile-object-is-not-subscriptable/13904